# Laravel AJAX validation: Return HTML instead of JSON

Tags: ajax, json, laravel-5

As it's stated in docs, if AJAX validation fails you get json response:

> If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.

But I'd prefer partial view with flashed error which is default for non AJAX.
So **is it possible to emulate non AJAX or turn off AJAX** without rebuilding source or some other awkwardness?

BTW, culprit function is buildFailedValidationResponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got into a similar problem these days and ended up overwriting a method as well.

Under Laravel 5.1.20, i had to copy method response from class Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest into class App\Http\Requests\Request, and just like your answer, changed

```
        if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson()) {
```

with

```
        if ($this->wantsJson())) {
```

This is the complete method in App\Http\Requests\Request class

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    if (!$this->pjax() && ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson())) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                            ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                            ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem with brute force. Just overwritten the trait method in AuthController. Bad feel about that.

```
protected function buildFailedValidationResponse(Request $request, array $errors) 
{ 
    if (/*$request->ajax() ||*/ $request->wantsJson()) { return new JsonResponse($errors, 422); 
}
```